# configure always_return_data based on param

Tags: django, api, rest, tastypie, patch

I'm using django tastypie, and would like to configure always_return_data to trigger true or false based on a patch vars specified (specifically a patch list update).

```
Example: patch to /api/v1/thisresource
data: {objects: {[name="john"]}, return_data: false}
```

Is there any way to configure this?

Comment: Can also configure always_return_data on all patch_lists for a specific resource if that's easier....

Answer (score 0):

I actually just made another custom resource for the specific patch's that had a ton of data to sift through, seems to have fixed in...